# Options for geotargeting content

Tags: ip-address, geolocation, geotargeting

My company is creating a web portal that is designed to put relevant local geographic data in front of our users. Aside from using IP addresses, which are increasingly becoming less reliable as a geotargeting device, what options do we have?

Of the top of my head, there is the new Javascript/HTML5 Geolocation API as used in Safari for iPhone, but are there other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I'd just add the functionality to let the user decide. Aside from what you're already looking for there isn't a silver bullet that will allow you to be correct 100% of the time. Here and there companies like Google don't know where I am, so I wouldn't overthink this.

I'll just use the example of a restaurant review site, something which would obviously need to be geo-targeted. Aside from trying to divine where your user is, you should have a prominent showing of the location the user is in, e.g., "You are viewing reviews in Denver, Colorado - click to change".

If you're looking for repeat visitors then the users will pick up how to use your site, and after the first visit they'll *tell you* where they actually are.

Comment: I fully agree with you on this, but I'm still looking for anything else other than IP to get that initial geo data set up for the user.